# Calculate moment of inertia for Oz axis of solid described by $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} $

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}
$$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWHCD.png))

Calculate moment of inertia for Oz axis of solid described by expression above.

$$
\int_0^{\frac12R\sqrt2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_z^\sqrt{R^2-z^2}r^3\,dr\,dx\,dz
\,\frac{1}{\int_0^{\frac12R\sqrt2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_z^\sqrt{R^2-z^2}r\,dr\,dx\,dz} = \frac{R^2}{2}
$$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvBkH.png))

This is what I ended up doing. My final result is $\frac{MR^2}{2}$ where $M$ is the mass of solid. However this doesn't seem to be the right answer. What is the proper way to find the moment of inertia of this solid?

Comment: I converted the images into MathJax.  Please check that the conversion has been done correctly, and please learn to do this yourself in the future.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) are some tips.

Comment: You have $r$ (variable) in some places that you should have $R$ (constant). And your integration bounds are wrong. If you integrate over $r$ first, then you need to split it into two integrals: $$\int_{z=0}^{z=R/\sqrt2}\int_{r=0}^{r=z}\quad+\quad\int_{z=R/\sqrt2}^{z=R}\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}$$ If you integrate over $z$ first, then it can be a single integral: $$\int_{r=0}^{r=R}\int_{z=r}^{z=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$$ (And $\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}$ factors out as a constant, since the integrand doesn't depend on $\theta$.)

Comment: (Draw a picture if it helps; the lower surface is a cone, and the upper surface is a spherical cap.)

Comment: Sorry, my second line should be $$\int_{r=0}^{r=R/\sqrt2}\int_{z=r}^{z=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$$

Comment: @mr_e_man Good point with constant R. This is my mistake, I don't know yet how to type integrals here so I just included screenshot from website that automatically changed capital R to lowercase r. This however haven't changed the result that is MR^2/2 that is obtained when using constant R. Nevertheless I still don't see why my bounds are wrong. r starts from z (not to include cone) and ends at sqrt(R^2 - r^2) where it meets the sphere.

Comment: Think of $r$ as the distance along a horizontal line from the (vertical) $z$ axis. Such a line never intersects both the cone and the spherical cap. It intersects the $z$ axis ($r=0$) and either one of the two surfaces.

Comment: @BrianTung Big thanks for help, I will definitely learn this. I had no idea how this is done

Comment: @mr_e_man That's exactely how I'm thinking about r. However it will intersect both sphere (r = \sqrt{R^2 - z^2}) and cone( r = z).

Comment: It won't intersect both at the same time (for a fixed value of $z$). It intersects the cone when $z<R/\sqrt2$, and it intersects the spherical cap when $z>R/\sqrt2$.

Comment: I think you're thinking of a spherical ring, outside of the cone with $r>z$, rather than a spherical cap, on top of the cone with $r<z$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Please take a look at this to make sure we understand each other.
https://imgur.com/a/lMmTWdm

Comment: Yes, you have $r>z$, but the problem given has $r<z$. (And your $z$ axis is horizontal, while I imagine it vertical.)

Comment: @mr_e_man OMG you're right. I love you man. You have no idea how much time I spent looking for this mistake. Thank you!!!